# OSX Lion: Can I use "classic" mousewheel scrolling but keep "natural" trackpad scrolling?

Tags: osx-lion, scrolling

I recently upgraded from OSX Snow Leopard to OSX Lion version 10.7.1. So far, I'm enjoying the "natural" scrolling when using my trackpad. However, when scrolling with my mouse wheel, I'm having trouble making the switch to "natural" scrolling. It feels decidedly unnatural to me. Furthermore, I frequently switch between PC and Mac, and I'm confusing myself by constantly switching my mouse scrolling paradigm.

Is there a way to keep "Classic" scrolling on my mouse, but continue to use "Natural" scrolling for the trackpad?

I know that I can turn off natural scrolling in System Preferences -> Trackpad, but this setting affects both my mouse and my trackpad, and System Preferences > Mouse does not seem to have any options to change scroll direction.

I am willing to consider "creative" options if there is not an officially supported method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a [duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22220/10576) on Ask Different.

There is no offically supported method to do this, but there is a free program called [Scroll Reverser](http://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/) which allows you to reverse vertical or horizontal scrolling on the devices of your choice. It's working great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set up [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) to automatically toggle OS X natural scrolling on/off when I switch between using my trackpad & mouse.

I outlined exactly how to set it up step-by-step in this blog post: http://kellenmace.com/automate-trackpad-mouse-natural-scrolling-in-mac-os-x/

I looked at Scroll Reverser, but the developer describes a few downsides to using it on his website that I wanted to avoid. I'm happy to report that this ControlPlane solution is working perfectly. Hope that helps anyone still looking for a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.