# Using trackpad and mouse at the same time on OS X

Tags: macos, mouse, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OSX Lion: Can I use “classic” mousewheel scrolling but keep “natural” trackpad scrolling?](https://superuser.com/questions/330543/osx-lion-can-i-use-classic-mousewheel-scrolling-but-keep-natural-trackpad-s)

I found such strange behavior when using the trackpad together with a mouse.
I would like both of them to work in this way at the same time:

1. I want to disable mouse feature "Move content in the direction of finger movement when scrolling or navigating"
2. I want to enable trackpad's "Scroll direction: natural"

How can I do it at the same time? When I disable mouse's feature, it automatically disables trackpad's feature. And contra verse.

Answer (score 1):

Within the system preferences there is a trackpad and a mouse section.  You should be able to select how each works separately.

Comment: You're not. Changing one changes the other, and there's no automatic settings switch when moving between input devices.